# Predict function for ksvm is not found?

Tags: r, kernlab

I'm trying to use the function `predict.ksvm` from library `kernlab` in R.
I have been reading the documentation at the following link:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kernlab/versions/0.9-27/topics/predict.ksvm

The function ksvm is working, so it's just the predict function that is currently not working.

The code:

```
library(kernlab)
mySvm<-ksvm(x=as.matrix(train[,-4703]),y=train[,4703],kernel="vanilladot")
predSvm<-predict.ksvm(mySvm,newdata=test[,-4703])
```

The error:

```
Error in predict.ksvm(mySvm, newdata = test[, -4703]) : 
could not find function "predict.ksvm"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simply

```
predSvm <- predict(mySvm, newdata = test[,-4703])
```

It should work because `mySvm` is an object of class `ksvm` and an appropriate function *method* will be automatically chosen for it.

When you write

```
predSvm <- predict.ksvm(mySvm, newdata = test[,-4703])
```

it doesn't work because the `predict` method for the `ksvm` class is somewhat hidden from you, pretends not to exist. If it were an `S3` function, you could write `kernlab:::predict.ksvm`, but in this case it is an `S4` function, so you need `getMethod("predict", "ksvm")` as to see the function.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.